# Unable to run a very simple android app on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android app development.

I created a new a project on Android Studio, which can run on Ice cream sandwich and later versions.

Just added one activity : "Basic activiy" from the list of activities.
Then tried to run the app on emulator Nexus 5x.

But the app not running, and the gradle build shows 61 errors.

I am listing some of the errors below:

```
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)

Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)

Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)

Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)

Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)

Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)

Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)

Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Error:Exception in thread "main" 

Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)

Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Error:Exception in thread "main" 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I don't understand what these errors mean.

Would be grateful if someone can help me out.

Comment: Did you register the new Activity in manifest?

Comment: Unsupported major/minor version typically indicates you are using a version of Java which is not supported by the code you trying to compile.  Suggest you check the documentation for the supported version.

Comment: Forget this project. Search for a nice'n'easy 101 tutorial and try again, this time making all things slowly, giving your best attention to all minor details. I am sure you will walk far away. If no, return here with punctual doubts. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. The problem got solved after I updated from JDK7 to JDK8.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation of Java is not proper, try to re-install Java JDK. Are you by any chance doing this on OS X? I had a similar problem earlier today. You have to delete the `tools.jar` in the OS X library for Java if so.